# How to import a managed service identity from a different subscription on terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a managed service identity `workflow-identity` living on subscription `A`. I set up another subscription `B` and set up a storage account `storageb`. I want to setup `azurerm_role_assignment` to let `A` access `storageb`. 
So I used :

> >terraform import azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example /subscriptions/[subscription-B]/resourceGroups/[resource-group-id]/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/workflow-identity
>   But it does not work. The reason I guess is because I am trying to import managed service identity from a different subscription. So my question is how to import from a different subscription in my case?

Here is my code example:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage1" {
    name                     = var.storage_account
    resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    account_tier             = "Standard"
    account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    name = "search-api"
    # subscription_id = 12333.   <---- not working. not supported.
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "storage_role" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.storage1.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.principal_id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create another azure provider and scope it to that subscription and use that provider to deploy the resource:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~>1.44"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "other_sub"
  subscription_id = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "ipv4" {
    provider = "azurerm.other_sub"
    name = zzz
    resource_group_name = yyy
    location = xxx
    allocation_method = "Static"
    ip_version = "IPv4"
    sku = "Standard"
}
```